# Add project in solution using NuGet

Tags: visual-studio, powershell, nuget

Currently I have a requirement to add multiple projects to a solution via NuGet package. I know that adding files to the solution is possible as described in [this link](http://www.vicesoftware.com/nuget/creating-a-nuget-package-that-will-install-files-relative-to-the-solution/), but I'm not able to add project in the solution. I wan't to know that it's possible or not and if possible how i achieve this. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is not really possible using a single command. If you are using install.ps1 scripts, you can choose to modify the sln file in the script.

E.g If you open a sln file that has a project you can see the following

> Project("{Project Guid}") = "ProjectName", "Relative path to project", "{Project Guid}"

In your install.ps1 script, you can crack open the sln and insert a similar entry for each of your projects during install.

Do note, this is probably something you will have to use [nuget commandline](https://dist.nuget.org/index.html) for,

> nuget install

since there is no easy UI way of installing NuGet packages to a solution in VS 2015.